# Is summing a function over all subsets in PP?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, decision-problem

Consider the following decision problem:

Input: a set $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$, a mapping $f \colon 2^X \mapsto \mathbb{N}$ such that for $f(Y)$ is computed in polynomial time for any $Y \subseteq X$, and an integer $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Question: does $\sum_{Y \subseteq X}{f(Y)} \geq k$ hold?

1. Is this problem in the complexity class [$\mathsf{PP}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PP_(complexity))? If yes, which NP Turing machine decides it?

Additionally, for proving such a membership result:

2. Should we specify how $f$ is represented?
3. Should we assume that $f$ is polynomially bounded?

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: 1) What I had in mind is to solve the problem through a NP Turing machine where the acceptance condition is that a majority (more than half) of computation paths accept.  My intuition is that the problem is in PP as an NP machine induces a tree of depth n that allows to capture all subsets Y of X. At each leaf, it could compute f(Y) and somehow create f(X) accepting branches. Then additional accepting / rejecting branches would be created somewhere to make the rate of accepting states to 50%.

Comment: The problem is I lack experience with this class. I am more familiar with non-deterministic algorithms such as "1. guess a succinct candidate w; 2. check in polytime that w is a proof that the instance is a yes one" to prove membership in NP, than with Turing machines.

Comment: 2) I believe the representation of f needs not to be specified, if one wants to show membership for any f satisfying that definition.

3) I believe f needs not to be polynomially bounded, as the depth of the accepting / rejecting branches from the NP machine in point 1) would still be a polynomial in $|X|$.

Comment: The answer really depends on how $f$ is specified. If it is specified as a table of values, then you can compute the sum in linear time.

Comment: Are you not telling us parts of your exercise?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus if $f$ is specified extensively as a table, it can be done in linear time so the problem is in $\mathsf{PP}$ indeed. $f$ could also be specified as an algorithm written in size polynomial in |X|. I have actually already proved that the problem is $\mathsf{PP}$-hard in the general case, by reduction from MAJSAT. I want to prove that the problem is also inside $\mathsf{PP}$ for any specification of $f$, as far as $f(Y)$ is computed in polynomial time for any $Y \subseteq X$. I forgot to mention that assumption in the initial problem formulation and edited the problem accordingly.

Comment: Is $f$ given as a circuit?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide all relevant information in the question.  Don't just leave additional information in the comments; edit the question so that someone who encounters it for the first time only needs to read the question and doesn't need to read the comments.  Please also credit the original source of this exercise/problem.